# Poetry add <package> returns AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, dependency-management, python-poetry

I am trying to create a Python package using poetry. I haven't been able to replicate the steps described in
[documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/). When I try to add a dependancy, e.g.

```
poetry add pendulum
```

I get

```
jan@jan-XPS-13-9380:~/Documents/Simosol/tmp/poetry-test$ poetry add pendulum
Using version ^2.1.2 for pendulum

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (1.0s)

  AttributeError

  __enter__

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/poetry/utils/helpers.py:98 in download_file
       94│     url, dest, session=None, chunk_size=1024
       95│ ):  # type: (str, str, Optional[requests.Session], int) -> None
       96│     get = requests.get if not session else session.get
       97│ 
    →  98│     with get(url, stream=True) as response:
       99│         response.raise_for_status()
      100│ 
      101│         with open(dest, "wb") as f:
      102│             for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
```

This happens with every package I've tried (pandas, geopandas, numpy, shapely). I don't understand much what is the problem and I haven't found any similar questions on GitHub or here.

**Question:** What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

I use Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6.9

Comment: This looks like problem with downloading, does `pip install package` work?

Comment: thanks for the tip! pip3 install <package> works fine. pip install <package> throws an error. but i understand poetry is using python3.

Comment: Are there any other Python installations on your system? Have you verified that Poetry is using the one you expect it to use?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have Python 2.7, 3.6 and 3.9. Would you please advise how to verify which one is Poetry using?

Comment: in the myproject.toml config file, python version is specified as

 [tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.6"

Comment: I don't actually know offhand. You might have better luck on superuser.com, though, since the problem is definitely *something* to do with your installation and not with any code you wrote. My other guess is that you need to update `requests` for your 3.6 install, but Poetry is supposed to have taken care of that when it installed.

Comment: How did you install poetry?

Comment: Looks like maybe you installed with `pip install --user poetry`, right? Maybe run `pip check` to see if you have incompatible dependencies.

Comment: @sinoroc i did python3 -m pip install poetry

Comment: OK, then run `python3 -m pip check` and see if dependency conflicts are detected.

Comment: @sinoroc thanks! I did and I fixed the conflicts but I still get the same error

Comment: Hard to tell... Have you tried other installation methods? You can try poetry's own recommended installation method. Personally I would recommend looking into installing poetry with a tool like [_pipx_](https://pypi.org/project/pipx/) or maybe another thing like that, the point is to try to install poetry so that it is isolated from other libraires/tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, what worked for me was to reinstall poetry as described [in the docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/):

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python -
```

instead of

```
python3 -m pip install poetry
```